# Authentication into mobile app from compliant devices but without password

Tags: ios, mobile, mdm

I have a requirement to enable our corporate users to access an iOS mobile application without any password as long as their device is compliant with the MDM policy of the company.
The application will be only available to end users via Intune MDM or Jamf Pro which are the MDM solutions we use and we'd like the end users to access the mobile app as long as they access it from an MDM compliant device but no username/password input should be needed.

Any solutions to accomplish this -

1. Anything that could be checked by the app at the device level to enable this checking?
2. Any certificate based checks that could be applied? i.e allow the mobile app to only launch if it has a specific client certificate loaded on the device.

Comment: Use the MDM to deploy the app as a managed app?  How else would the app get on the device?

Comment: Microsoft have an [Intune SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/app-sdk-ios) that you can embed in your app to validate device posture.